# picking out elements based on complement of records in Python pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a python pandas DataFrame question.  There are two DataFrames containing records, **df1** and **df2**.  They contain the following values:

```
df1:
   pkid  start   end
0     0   2005  2005
1     1   2006  2006
2     2   2007  2007
3     3   2008  2008
4     4   2009  2009

df2:
   pkid  start   end
0     3   2008  2008
1   NaN   2009  2009
2   NaN   2010  2010
```

I am looking to isolate the record w/index=2 from **df2**.  In other words, I am looking to find all records of **df2** where there are not matching records in **df1** where only the start and end column values are considered.  Thanks!

Comment: Which rows of the dataframes shown do you want picked?  I don't under stand your criteria

Comment: i want the rows from df2 which do not have corresponding record matches for start and end in df1 (so, this disregards the values in the pkid column).  this case would yield the row indexed 2 from df2: NaN, 2010 2010.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This operation called [`antijoin (▷)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29) in relational algebra and SQL. I've tried to find native pandas operation for this, but found nothing.

But you can do it functional way, don't know about performance :)

```
>>> t1 = df1[["start", "end"]]
>>> t2 = df2[["start", "end"]]
>>> f = t2.apply(lambda x2: t1.apply(lambda x1: x1.isin(x2).all(), axis=1).any(), axis=1)
>>> df2[~f]
    end  pkid  start
2  2010   NaN   2010
```

---

**update**:
In SQL, it can be done by different ways, like `not exists`:

```
select *
from df2
where not exists (select * from df1 where df1.start = df2.start and df1.end = df2.end)
```

or `left outer join` with `where` clause:

```
select *
from df1
    left outer join df1 on df1.start = df2.start and df1.end = df1.end
where df1.<key> is null
```

Last one could be implemented in pandas with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra):

```
>>> m = pd.merge(df2, df1, how='left', on=['end','start'], suffixes=['','_r'])
>>> df2[m['pkid_r'].isnull()]
    end  pkid  start
2  2010   NaN   2010
```

Comment: btw, I had also been trying to find the native Pandas implementation, but also found nothing.  hopefully we'll find this in a future release.  i'd bet it'll be there sooner than later.  it has too much value.

Comment: @ant see another solution with pandas merge.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a key to the frames and then use 'isin' function

```
df1['key'] = df1.apply(lambda r: str(r['start']) + str(r['end']), axis=1)
df2['key'] = df2.apply(lambda r: str(int(r['start'])) + str(int(r['end'])), axis=1)

df2.key.isin(df1.key.tolist())
0    True
1    True
2    False


df2[~df2.key.isin(df1.key.tolist())]
pkid  start   end
2   NaN   2010  2010
```

Comment: Thank you!  This effectively works in this instance.  Although, I am left to wonder if there is a solution which would evaluate each record on a value-by-value consideration.  In any event, much appreciated!