# How do I check if a date in my range is in my csv file containing a column of dates

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of dates in my CSV file which when imported and parsed gives me the below output

```
df = pd.read_csv('datelist.csv',parse_dates=['date'])
df.head(5)
    date
0   2020-04-01
1   2020-04-02
2   2020-04-03
3   2020-04-04
4   2020-04-05

type(df.date[0])
pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp

I have a range as below

myrange = pd.date_range(start=start_date,end=end_date)

DatetimeIndex(['2020-04-24', '2020-04-25', '2020-04-26', '2020-04-27',
               '2020-04-28', '2020-04-29', '2020-04-30', '2020-05-01',
               '2020-05-02', '2020-05-03', '2020-05-04', '2020-05-05',
               '2020-05-06', '2020-05-07', '2020-05-08', '2020-05-09',
               '2020-05-10'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

I want to check if each item in myrange if it is present in df.date column and do some code, so i am trying this but all result come to false

```
for i in rng:
    if i in df.date[:]:
        print('is in the df')
    else:
        print('is not in the list')
```

output i get is "is not in the list" for all items

any suggestions on this please

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070194/isin-function-does-not-work-for-dates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ISIN function does not work for dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070194/isin-function-does-not-work-for-dates)