# pandas `isin()` function strange behavior on pd.date_range and datetime type

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, bug-reporting, isin

I tried to use `isin()` to filter datetime column in my df. Found the following strange behavior:

Let's define a dataframe with a sole date value:

```
>>>from datetime import datetime
>>>date = datetime.fromisoformat('2011-11-04')
>>>df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [date]})
>>>print(df)
        date
0 2011-11-04
```

We set a date range of 2 days:

```
>>>date_rg = pd.date_range(end='2011-11-04', periods=2)
```

The date is expected to be in the range:

```
>>>date in date_rg
True
```

***However, if we use `isin()`, strange things happen!***

```
>>>df.date.dt.date.isin(date_rg)
0    False
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

With further investigation, I find even stranger behavior:

```
>>>for i in range(1,10):
>>>    date_rg = pd.date_range(end='2011-11-04', periods=i)
>>>    print('i =', i)
>>>    print(df.date.dt.date.isin(date_rg))

i = 1
0    False
Name: date, dtype: bool
i = 2
0    False
Name: date, dtype: bool
i = 3
0    True
Name: date, dtype: bool
i = 4
0    False
Name: date, dtype: bool
i = 5
0    True
Name: date, dtype: bool
i = 6
0    True
Name: date, dtype: bool
i = 7
0    True
Name: date, dtype: bool
i = 8
0    True
Name: date, dtype: bool
i = 9
0    True
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

***Only when period = 1, 2 and 4 days, it returns False!***
I strongly suspect it's a bug of Pandas lib.
I'm using `pandas:1.0.5` with `numpy:1.19.0`.

By the way, we are able to contour this by using `date_range.date`:

```
>>>df.date.dt.date.isin(date_rg.date)
0    True
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

*Related:
[isin-function-does-not-work-for-dates.](http://%22https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070194/isin-function-does-not-work-for-dates%22.)
[Issue 5021](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5021).

Comment: As per the duplicate, there used to be an error message in `0.25` that stated things would not necessrily compare equal. `datetime.date` and `np.timedelta64[ns]` are different objects. Though they should represent the same thing, there's no reason they should be equal. Compare `datetime64` with `datetime64` or `datetime.date` with `datetime.date` and all comparisons work properly.

Comment: Thank you @ALollz for pointing out the root cause!   It's still really confusing though: e.g. in my last example with different periods, I would expect a consistent False since they are different types, as you point out. But why are they "randomly" True in some cases?    Just my uninformed guess: Perhaps it's because the `datetime.date` and `datetime.date` objects are very close in their underlying lower-level encodings, so sometimes their encodings of the same date overlap?